# TypeScript Assertion Doesn't work when the property is Record<number,number>

Tags: typescript

I learn from some blog that `T as K` in typescript only work when `T is subType of K` or `K is subType of T`,I don't know whether it's true of not.

And when I using `as` when the property is `Record<T,K>`,`as` throw some error as below.

```
interface Test {
    x: Record<number, number>;
    y: number;
}


// this is wrong, but {1: 1} should be subType of Record<number,number>
const x1 = {
    x: { 1: 1 },
} as Test;

// this is okay
const x2 = {
    y: 1,
} as Test;

// this is okay too
const x3 = {
    x: { 1: 1 },
    y: 1,
} as Test;
```

First, I guess It's because `{ 1: 1 }` doesn't match the Type `Record<number, number>`, I guess the subType judge is shallow. But here is another sample that can work.

```
interface SubTest {
    x: 1;
    y: 1;
}
interface Test2 {
    x: SubTest;
    y: number;
}

// { x: 1 } is subType of SubTest, and It works!
const x4 = {
    x: { x: 1 },
} as Test2;
```

You can see `{x:1}` doesn't match `SubTest` too, but this assertion can work, so I guess it's a special problem of `Record<T,K>`,can anyone tell me why? thanks a lot!

---

I found out this one can work! so I'm really cofunsed right now...

```
interface Test {
    x: Record<number, number>;
    y: number;
}

const x4 = {
    x: { a: 1 },
    y: 1,
} as Test;
```

Comment: I don't know the exact rules by which types are considered "sufficiently related" to allow assertions, but `Record<K, T>` (`K` is generally first, since it means "key") is probably not directly related; a type like `Record<number, number>` becomes an indexable type like `{[k: number]: number}`, so you might consider rephrasing this question in terms of index signatures and not `Record`.

Comment: Looks like [microsoft/TypeScript#30342](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30342) at first glance

Answer (score 0):

The problem with below is not with the `Record`. In interface `Test` you have defined `y` as mandatory but you have not provided y here.

```
const x1 = {
    x: { 1: 1 },
} as Test;
```

Convert `y` to optional like below.

Change this

```
interface Test {
    x: Record<number, number>;
    y: number;
}
```

To

```
interface Test {
    x: Record<number, number>;
    y?: number;
}
```

Now `y` is made optional with `?`. This should make your code compile.

Comment: this is a way to solve this problem, but you see,
`const x2 = { y: 1,} as Test; `can work, so I dont think it is the problem